# TPM Key Generation

Tags: tpm

How I can use a persisted primary key to generate child key.I want to use persistent handle and I am using ESYS API.

After loading persisted primary key whenever I am using Esys_Create it is showing error code 0x98e
I am using tpm 2.0 simulator

Comment: Please show your efforts as a minimal reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The error code `0x98e` means `tpm:session(1):the authorization HMAC check failed and DA counter incremented`. I used `tpm2_rc_decode` which is part of the tpm2-tools to find that out.